# opencv: image with grid and HIGHGUI error

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I'm new to opencv(version 2.4.7) and using it in python 2.7.4. I always get this error

> HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP

whenever I use the command

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_id)
```

The code works fine otherwise even with the error. I'm trying to use [this wireless camera](http://www.pollin.de/shop/dt/MTU4OTE0OTk-/Haustechnik/Sicherheitstechnik/Kameras/Zusatzkamera_Kanal_4.html) and it shows an image which has a magenta and green colored grid structure. My question is why am I getting the error and this weird image. The code gives nice image on other system also on my system itself. gstreamer-properties also have clear picture. The code:

```
from cv2 import cv
import cv2
import sys

def main(): 

cam_id = 0

# parameter
for i, arg in enumerate( sys.argv ):
    if i == 0: continue
    else: cam_id = arg

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_id)

cv2.namedWindow("window", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

running = True

while running:
    try:
        flag, img = cam.read()
        if flag:
            cv2.imshow("window", img)
            cv2.waitKey(30)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        running = False

cv2.destroyWindow("window")

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to update so late, I had figured out solution of the issue long ago but forgot to answer it here. It required loading a library before running the code. Use of following commands should do the trick.

For 32bit system:

> `$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so python filename.py`

For 64bit system:

> `$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so python filename.py`

If this doesn't work then try locating the file v4l2convert.so by using command,

> `$ locate v4l2convert.so`

As the output you'll see different paths, now try LD_PRELOAD with different paths.